# Copying range from one sheet and pasting as image in another, all while resizing the image

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel document where I want to take a range of cells from one sheet, and paste them as an image in a different sheet, but, re-size the image for printing purposes.

I have my small macro, written with help of the Record Macro button.  It lifts the range and places it where I want, as an image, but I am unsure of how to resize this image in VBA (I want to make it smaller).

```
Sub heatmapToJPEG()

    Range("H1:U30").Select
    Selection.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
    Sheets("PDF Page").Select
    Range("A27").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

I thought I could create an `object` variable and store the new image to that object.  But I am either doing it incorrectly, or there is a better way.  Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do either

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1")).Select
    Selection.ShapeRange.Width = 100
```

or  `Selection.ShapeRange.Height = 136.8`